# Unary NOT in SQLite FTS5 MATCH query

Tags: sqlite, match, full-text-search, fts5

The [SQLite FTS5 docs](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#fts5_boolean_operators) say that search queries such as `SELECT ... WHERE MATCH '<query1> NOT <query2>'` are supported, but it looks like there's no support for the unary `NOT` operator.

For example, if I want to search for *everything* that *doesn't* match `<query>`, I cannot use `MATCH 'NOT <query>'`. I would have to use `NOT MATCH '<query>'`, which is a completely different thing (the FTS5 module never gets to see the `NOT` operator, as it is outside the quotation marks). Only the text inside the quotation marks is the search query.

I need to find a way to use an unary `NOT` operator *inside the search query*. I can't use it outside, because I only get to control the search query text, and not the rest of the SQL statement.

A possible approach I've thought of would be to find a search query that matches anything, and do `MATCH '<match_anything> NOT <query>'`. However, I've found no way to match everything in a search query.

Can you think of a way to **have the behaviour of the unary `NOT` operator inside the search query**?

Answer (score 1):

Or try this:

```sql
(technology OR pace) NOT mobile
```

https://sqlite.org/fts5.html (section 3.7)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
SELECT * FROM docs
WHERE ROWID NOT IN ( 
  SELECT ROWID FROM docs WHERE content MATCH '<query>'
)
```

Comment: Good idea! However, as I stated in my original question, I need to find a way to use an unary `NOT` operator _**inside the search query**_. Here, it is outside, so in my case, it's not useful... However, in a general case, it does indeed work as a workaround!